# Where does 'parabolic' in the definition of parabolic subgroups of an algebraic group come from?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, algebraic-groups

A parabolic subgroup $P$ of an algebraic group $G$ is defined as a subgroup containing the Borel subgroup $B$ of $G$. Why is this terminology used? What is the motivation behind it?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93742/why-are-parabolic-subgroups-called-parabolic-subgroups